# Java reading a file containing text and sending to the output file, by preceding the text by line numbers

Tags: java

Write a program that reads a file containing text. Read each line and send it to the output file, preceded by line numbers. The line numbers are enclosed in   delimiters so that the program can be used for numbering Java source files. Prompt the user for the input and output file names.

For example, if the text is

An apple fell
I picked it up

The output should look like
/*1*/An apple fell
/*2*/I picked it up

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class LineNumberer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedWriter output = null;

        try {
            FileWriter hellotext = new FileWriter("hello.txt");       //Editing the file
            output = new BufferedWriter(hellotext);
            output.write("Hello World!");
            System.out.println("the hello.txt File has been edited");
        } catch (IOException error) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + error.getMessage());      //File corruption or not found message)
        } finally {
            if (output != null) {
                output.close();
            }
        }
        BufferedReader in1 = null;
        try {
            FileReader hellotext = new FileReader("hello.txt");
            in1 = new BufferedReader(hellotext);
            String textfile1 = in1.readLine();
            System.out.println("Data in file: ");
            System.out.println(textfile1);
        } catch (IOException error) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + error.getMessage());      //File corruption or  not found message)
        } finally {
            if (in1 != null) {
                in1.close();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The problem that I am having here is in these lines

```
        int j = 0;

        while (j <= i) {
        String filedata = "/*"+(j+1)+"*/"+textfile[i++];
```

They keep throwing indexarray out of bounds error.

Also, i am confused about what value should I give for the array size in

```
        String textfile[] = new String[10];
        int i =0;
```

I gave the value a 10, but should I increase it or alter it in any way?

Comment: `while (j < i) {` maybe? You might also like to take a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: It might be simpler (and safer) to read a line from the input from, process it and write it out to the output file within a single loop.  This removes any issues with knowing how many lines there are in the input file

Comment: @Mish Did you post the correct source?

Comment: Sorry it's my first time posting here so i messed up the format. I fixed it now. This should fix the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `java.nio` package and a `PrintWriter` along with "try-with-resource", that will take care of closing readers and writers :

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        if(args.length != 2)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal number of arguments.  Usage:\n\t java foo.bar.Test <sourceFile> <destFile> ..");

        Path source = Paths.get(args[0]);
        Path destination = Paths.get(args[1]);
        try(
            BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(source, Charset.defaultCharset());
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(destination, Charset.defaultCharset()));
        ) {
            int lineNumber = 1;
            String line = null;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                writer.format("/%d/%s%n", lineNumber++,line);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the size of the input file, `String[] textfile = new String[10]` is not safe. No number other than 10 is safe either. You should be using `ArrayList<String>` if you want to slurp up a file of unknown length. Alternatively, if the length of the file is in the first line of the file, you could read that number in first and then use `String[]`.

However, it is probably best as MadProgrammer recommends to open the input and output streams at the same time, read a line from the input, print out the augmented output, increment the line number variable, and loop until there are no more input lines.